# Is there a shorthand for declaring a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working with 2 dimensional arrays and I need a way to declare the number of inner arrays.  Right now I'm using something like this:

```
var purchasePermutationP0Array = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];
```

which has 28 inner brackets.  What I want is to be able to declare how many inner brackets there are without using so many "[]".  Is there a way to do that in javascript?  Something like:

```
var purchasePermutationP0Array = [new Array [28]]?
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can populate your array with a loop ...

Comment: No, there is not a language shorthand for declaring a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop-

```
var i=0, purchasePermutationP0Array = [];
while(i++<28)purchasePermutationP0Array.push([]);
```